# Promise pending for fetch request inside puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am attempting login into a site with my credentials, then waiting for the page to navigate and finally sending a post request to an endpoint once logged in. However, I find that my promise is always pending, for example:

Here is a snippet:

```
    await page.goto('https://id.adform.com/sts/login')
    await Promise.all([
        page.evaluate(() => {
            (function() {const setValue = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
              window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,
              "value").set;
              const modifyInput = (name, value) => {
              const input = document.getElementsByName(name)[0]
              setValue.call(input, value)
              input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true}))
              };
              modifyInput('username', "another");
              modifyInput('password', "some.123");
              document.querySelector("button").click();
              }())
          }),
        page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}),
    ]);
    await page.evaluate(() => {fetch('https://page_after_navigation.com', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.json_data_)
    }).then( (response) => {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data); // this will be a string
    })
})
```

This would enter the page, fill in the form, submit the button and wait for page navigation. Then fetch the page request where the cookies after taken from the page navigation and used inside the fetch request.

Comment: "I find that my promise is always pending" — Which promise? You appear to have at least seven in that bit of code!

Comment: "This would enter the page, fill in the form, submit the button and wait for page navigation. Then I should" — Then you should what?

Comment: promise will always stays in pending state unless you enclose it in try catch or execute .then statement. you need to add .then block in call.

Comment: @Quentin The last `page.evaluate`, it should return the content of the fetched data but promise is pending.`

Comment: `await page.evaluate(() => {fetch('https://page_after_navigation.com', {` — How can you tell that it is pending?

Comment: @Quentin After checking with my code I seem to be getting the promise pending from something else. I removed parts of the code to confirm, just do not know where! How can I get the data from fetch or is this pending promise preventing it from happening?

Comment: Mixing async/await and then is a great way to confuse yourself with promises. Please share a [mcve] to get help.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, if promise is pending, you are missing async/await somewhere in your code implementation.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. You can comment at 50 rep.